# Generating a random number between a range with a weight/bias?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, random

I am trying to generate a random number between 1 and a maximum. This I don't have a problem doing so and do so with the following:

```
var max = 200;    
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
```

However in an ideal situation I would like to generate a number between 1 and my maximum however the lower numbers have a higher probability of occurring. I want the variable to be biased towards 1. However my maths skills aren't strong enough to work this out, it would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you,

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple way will be to just square the result of Math.random(). Since the result of the function is between 0 and 1 , the square will also be in the range [0, 1], but values , for example , 0.5 from it will be mapped to lower ones - 0.25 . You can experiment with powers above 1 until you find an acceptable function.

Answer (score 1):

I got a code in java which does what you want.
You should choose your own probabilities for the int[] prob arrays.
I think it wont be that hard to translate this to js or build smth. equal.

```
int[] probs;

void initRandom(int n, int[] probabilities)
{
    int i,j,begin=0,end=0,sum=0;
    int[] probs;
    // sum of all propabilitys must be 100% 
    for(i=0;i<probabilities.length;i++) sum+=probabilities[i];
    probs=new int[sum];
    // fills numbers from 0 till n-1 in regard to their probabilities
    // to the probability array.

     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         begin=end;
         end+=probabilities[i];
         for(j=begin;j<end;j++) probs[j]=i;
     }
}

int genRandom()
{
    return probs[smallRand(probs.length-1)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question. First consider this link here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_a_bounded_interval
It shows some probability functions which are bounded, which I believe is what you are looking for (since min=1 and max=max).
You can also chose a semi-infine interval, and just ignore all value above your maximum. I think, this could also be acceptable, depending on your application.

Next, chose one of those probabilty functions, that suits you best. For the sake of simplicity, I chose the triangular distribution

The distribution functions are (PDF and CDF)

```
f(x) = 2/(2*max-1-max^2)*(x-max)
F(x) = 2/(2*max-1-max^2)*(0.5*x^2-max*x-0.5+max)
```

so I can generate from a uniform distribution on 0-1 a biased distribution by inverting the CDF like

```
var urand = Math.random();
var a = 2/(2*max-1-max^2);
var randomNumber = max-Math.sqrt(max*max-2*(max-urand/a-0.5));
```

Cheers
R

Answer (score 0):

The following function i made up gives you a near-one-biased random number

```
function rand(max) {
    var r = Math.random();
    r = 1/(101-100 * r);
    return Math.floor(r * max) - 1;
}
```

It only uses simple arithmetics, thus, it should be quite fast.